# Unexpected token # in JSON at position 0 with Angular 5 and Express JS

Tags: angular5

I am developing a MEAN stack application

```
where My client is in Angular 5 and backend is in node and express js with mongo db as my storage.

I am trying to upload an image from one my Angular Page to my express js rest API which will finally upload the image in AWS cloud

Sample code for my Component is as below having two methods one onFileSelected which sets the selected file and the onUpload which invokes a service class method


private selectedFile:File=null;


onUpload(){
    this.productCategoryService.
    uploadProductCategoryImage(this.selectedFile).subscribe(
      data=>{console.log("Upload success---"+data)},
      err=>{console.log("Upload error ---"+err.message)});
}


onFileSelected(event){
    this.selectedFile=event.target.files[0];
    console.log("this.selectedFile---------"+this.selectedFile);
}

The service does a post call of rest service on express js.Code of my service class is as below


public uploadProductCategoryImage(selectedFile:File){
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("userFile",selectedFile);
        return this.http.post<any>
        ('http://localhost:3000/datastore/api/aws/api/file',formData);       
}

My html page

<input type="file" (change)="onFileSelected($event)" name="userFile">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" (click)="onUpload()">
<span class="fa fa-upload"></span>Upload</button>

However when I post this data I get an error as below on the server side

SyntaxError: Unexpected token # in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

I found something from my browser.It shows BAD request.
I am not sure what is happening.Please suggest.

General------------
Request URL: http://localhost:3000/datastore/api/aws/api/file
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 400 Bad Request
Remote Address: [::1]:3000
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Response Header------------
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 1314
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Fri, 22 Jun 2018 16:47:12 GMT
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Powered-By: Express

Request Header--------------------
Accept: application/json
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 232378
Content-Type: application/json
Host: localhost:3000
Origin: http://localhost:4200
Referer: http://localhost:4200/contactus
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.62 Safari/537.36
------WebKitFormBoundaryAEgWhmyP5LdwDaEl
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="userFile"; filename="Screenshot from 2018-06-04 20-23-28.png"
Content-Type: image/png

Thanks
Sachin

Answer (score 2):

In Angular 5 Httpclient uses JSON as default format. So you have use **BLOB** as your response type like

```
  getImage(imageUrl: string): Observable<Blob> {
    return this.httpClient.get(imageUrl, { responseType: 'blob' });
  }
```

Check this link for reference: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1yr75s?file=src%2Fapp%2Fimage.service.ts